# How to use TensorFlow tf.data.Dataset flat_map to produce a derived dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a Pandas DataFrame, and I'm loading part of it into a tf.data Dataset:

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    df.StringColumn.values,
    df.IntColumn1.values,
    df.IntColumn2.values,
))
```

Now what I would like to do is to use something like `flat_map` to produce a derived Dataset that takes the data in each row and produces a bunch of rows in the derived Dataset for each row in the original.

But `flat_map` seems to just pass me placeholder tensors in the `lambda` function.

I'm using TensorFlow 2.0 alpha 0 if that matters.

**Edit:**

What I'd like is to be able to write something like this:

```py
derived = dataset.flat_map(replicate)

def replicate(s, i1, i2):
    return [[0, s, i1, i2],
        [0.25, s, i1, i2],
        [0.5, s, i1, i2],
        [0.75, s, i1, i2]]
```

... and then have `derived` be a Dataset with four columns and four times as many rows as `dataset`.

But when I try this, `s` isn't a value, it's a string placeholder tensor.

**Edit 2:**

Okay, what I meant is that the `replicate` function needs to know the values of the row it's replicating:

```py
slice_count = 16

def price(frac, total, size0, price0, size1, price1, size2, price2, size3, price3):
    total_per_slice = total / slice_count
    start = frac * total_per_slice
    finish = start + total_per_slice
    price = \
        (price0 * (min(finish, size0) - max(start, 0) if 0 < finish and start < size0 else 0)) + \
        (price1 * (min(finish, size1) - max(start, size0) if size0 < finish and start < size1 else 0)) + \
        (price2 * (min(finish, size2) - max(start, size1) if size1 < finish and start < size2 else 0)) + \
        (price3 * (min(finish, size3) - max(start, size2) if size2 < finish and start < size3 else 0))

def replicate(size0, price0, size1, price1, size2, price2, size3, price3):
    total = size0 + size1 + size2 + size3
    return [[
        price(frac, total, size0, price0, size1, price1, size2, price2, size3, price3),
        frac / slice_count] for frac in range(slice_count)]

derived = dataset.flat_map(replicate)
```

It's not sufficient to just be able to pass placeholders along. Is this something I can do, or is it doable if I can somehow translate it into TensorFlow's calculation graphs, or is it just not doable the way I'm trying to do it?

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and output you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a long way around but you can also use `.concatenate()` with `apply()` to achieve a 'flat mapping'

something like this:

```
def replicate(ds):
  return (ds.map(lambda s,i1,i2: (s, i1, i2, tf.constant(0.0)))
          .concatenate(ds.map(lambda s,i1,i2: (s, i1, i2, tf.constant(0.25))))
          .concatenate(ds.map(lambda s,i1,i2: (s, i1, i2, tf.constant(0.5))))
          .concatenate(ds.map(lambda s,i1,i2: (s, i1, i2, tf.constant(0.75)))))

derived = dataset.apply(replicate)
```

should give you the output you were expecting